# best android game development engine

Tags: android

What is a good android game development engine to start with? I was thinking game salad or game maker studio or construct2. Are they all basically the same or is one better than the other?

Answer (score 2):

Which is "better" is very relative.

Check [Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) and [Unity](https://unity3d.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Its all a mix of personal preference and complexity of your game. 
While tools like Game Maker Studio may help you create games, their complexity is limited to what may be pre-built into the program. Authoring tools like Unity offer a much larger array of tools and generally have alot more freedom when it comes to including what you want in a game but of course come at a price, both monetarily and complexity of use (more in depth scripting).

A general tip I like to give folks that want to start game development (or any development for that matter) is, try to find something that has a very large, active community. They tend to offer really good tips and help to better increase your understanding of what you're working with.

Comment: I have played with Game maker studio before , there was a large  community , I should have mentioned that I am thinking I would like to do something 2D

Comment: Unity offers tools to build 2D games with it as well. If you check out the http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials page, there is a dedicated section for 2D game development. You can include 3D elements as well into a 2D game.
I personally have not worked with Game Maker Studio that much but I do know alot of it is sort of "Pre-programmed" and has a cookie-cutter feel to it

Comment: maybe you should check this article on Wikipedia which compares different game engines and their programming languages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines)

Comment: I am torn between Unity and Game Maker. It seems like Unity is more robust and you can write actual code, but may be geared more for 3D , where game maker on the other hand is more for 2D , but is limited.

Comment: As a personal opinion, I prefer Unity. It has everything you need for 2D that you could possibly get from Game Maker Studio plus more. I would give it a shot. Worst case scenario? You'll find out you don't like Unity :)